# Web api attribute routing, by content type, in dot net core 2?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'd like to be able to consume either posted JSON or form data at the same URL.

As things stand, I get:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionSelector[1]
      Request matched multiple actions resulting in ambiguity. Matching actions: 
:
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HLDLB0LJCPJ4", Request id "0HLDLB0LJCPJ4:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:
```

https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/ suggests using different endpoints, but I can't do that in this case.

https://massivescale.com/web-api-routing-by-content-type/ suggests a way to do it for asp.net, for example:

```
[ContentTypeRoute("api/test/bytype", "application/json")]
```

or

```
[ContentTypeRoute("api/test/bytype", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
```

but in .net core, we don't have System.Web.Http.Routing.  Maybe it can be ported to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing... but is there something to replace IHttpRouteConstraint

My question: is something like this already built into .net core mvc?

For example, in Java's JAX-RS, there is @Consumes("application/json")

Comment: Now see also https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7755

Answer (score 27):

I accomplished this by the Consumes attribute:

http://example.com/payment/callback - Accepts x-www-form-urlencoded.

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("callback")]
[Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
public ActionResult Post([FromForm] string value)
{

}
```

http://example.com/payment/callback - Same url but accepts application/json.

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("callback")]
[Consumes("application/json")]
public ActionResult Post([FromBody] JObject value)
{

}
```

Comment: I wondered why this answer wasn't accepted. And it appears that due to a bug this will not work with CORS together. The workaround can be found here: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7755#issuecomment-387681022

Comment: Well, I thought I was answering the question.  I did prototype this before posting the solution.  Apparently, missed the CORS reference.  Perhaps the question be edited to provide more clarity?

Comment: Who looking for answer **please attentions**:  `[Consumes("application/json")]` is `[FromBody]` and `[Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]` is `[FromForm]`