# ASP.NET Core FromForm And FromBody Same Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Can I have both FromForm and FromBody attributes to action ?

```
public IActionResult Index([FromBody][FromForm] Person model){
.....
}
```

Comment: When someone send request from postman and have provided the data in raw section to be mapped to the model but in the same time to work with  forms.

Comment: Look it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50245160 There is a way to solve your task.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

The `FromForm` attribute is for incoming data from a submitted form sent by the content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
while the `FromBody` will parse the model the default way, which in most cases are sent by the content type `application/json`, from the request body.

Comment: As @Nodon mentions, it IS possible, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/51735331/2276157

Comment: @kloarubeek yes, its possible on different actions, not on the same.

Comment: The signature of the action still needs to differ

Comment: BTW this is a downgrade from the old ".NET Framework" where one action method would bind to all possible inputs

Answer (score 7):

Please look at this library
https://github.com/shamork/Toycloud.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.BodyAndFormBinding

I used the source and modified a bit as there is an issue with .Net 5 with ComplexTypeModelBinderProvider being obsolete

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.binders.complextypemodelbinderprovider?view=aspnetcore-5.0

In short, this prevents having to do this

```
    public class JsonRequestItem {
        public string jsonRequest { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("NewRequest")]
    [Consumes("application/json")]
    public IActionResult NewRequestFromBody([FromBody]JsonRequestItem item) {
        return NewRequest(item.jsonRequest);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("NewRequest")]
    [Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
    public IActionResult NewRequestFromForm([FromForm]JsonRequestItem item) {
        return NewRequest(item.jsonRequest);
    }

    private IActionResult NewRequest(string jsonRequest) {
        return new EmptyResult(); // example
    }
```

Now you can simplify as one action and get both FromBody and FromForm

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("NewRequest")]
    public IActionResult NewRequestFromBodyOrDefault([FromBodyOrDefault]JsonRequestItem item) {
        return new EmptyResult(); // example
    }
```