# How to accept a File and a Json data in Post endpoint in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I am using Aradalis Endpoints package. For a Post endpoint i want to accept a file and object as json which i deserialize.

Here is my endpoint code

```cs
namespace App.API.Endpoints.ExecuteQueryTasks
{
    public sealed class CreateExecutionResultEndpoint : EndpointBaseAsync
        .WithRequest<CreateQueryResultRequest>
        .WithActionResult<ExecutionResult>
    {
        public const string RouteName = "ExecuteQueryTasks.StoreResult";

        private readonly ISender _sender;
        private readonly ILogger<CreateExecutionResultEndpoint> _logger;

        public CreateExecutionResultEndpoint(ISender sender, ILogger<CreateExecutionResultEndpoint> logger)
        {
            _sender = sender ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sender));
            _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        }

        [HttpPost("/tasks/result")]
        public override async Task<ActionResult<ExecutionResult>> HandleAsync([FromForm] CreateQueryResultRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                foreach (var state in ModelState)
                {
                    foreach (var error in state.Value.Errors)
                    {
                        _logger.LogError("Validation error: {ErrorMessage}", error.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Handling CreateExecutionResult request");

                var resultData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExecutionResult>(request.Result);
                ...
                return Created(getByIdUrl, result.Value);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while handling CreateExecutionResult request");

                return StatusCode(500, "An unexpected error occurred");
            }
        }
    }
}

public class CreateQueryResultRequest
{
    public string Result { get; set; }

    public IFormFile? File { get; set; }
}
```

This works but when i try to accept `Result` as type `ExecutionResult` and give it a attribute `[FromBody]` and `File` the the attribute `[FromForm]`. Then i give my `CreateExecutionRequest` `[FromBody]` attribute. This give me 415 unsupported type response when sending data to post endpoint.

Here is my sending code:

```cs
using var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("AppClient");
            try
            {
                using var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();

                 if (data is not null) 
                {
                    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                    await using var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    await using JsonTextWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter);

                    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                    serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, data);
                    await jsonWriter.FlushAsync();

                    memoryStream.Position = 0;

                    var streamContent = new StreamContent(memoryStream);

                    streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                    multipartContent.Add(streamContent, "File", "data.json");
                }
                

                var metadataJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
                multipartContent.Add(new StringContent(metadataJson), "Result");

                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("/tasks/result", multipartContent);

                var res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return Result.Error(new Error("error", "Error occured while sending data to QueryHub"));
                }

                return Result.Success();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Result.Error(new Error("error", ex.Message));
            }
```

This is the class i am trying to deserialize my result into.

```cs
public sealed class ExecutionResult
    {
        public ExecutionResult();

        public Guid ResultId { get; set; }
        public Guid TaskId { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan TimeElapsed { get; set; }
        public ExecutionStatusEnum Status { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Error> Errors { get; set; }
        public string FileUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

Here `ExecutionStatusEnum` is `Ardalis SmartEnum`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have both `FromForm` and `FromBody` attributes in one action.

Referring the official document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0 , [FromForm] gets values from posted form fields, [FromBody] gets values from the request body. In one http request it cannot bind data to the parameters from both sources once. That's why you got 415. There are also some discussions on this [ASP.NET Core FromForm And FromBody Same Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50453578/asp-net-core-fromform-and-frombody-same-action) .

You can use `multipart/form-data` and `[FromForm]` to send both the file and the string within the form data.