# How to use [FromBody] and [FromForm] on the same url?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

Client can send me data in `JSON` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format. How can i process this requests without separation to diffrent urls? I tried two cases. It don't work;
Case 1:

```
[Route ( "api/[controller]" )]
[ApiController]
public class FirstController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string SomePostFromBody ( [FromBody] TestClass obj )
    {
        return obj.Prop1 + obj.Prop2;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public string SomePostFromForm ( [FromForm] TestClass obj )
    {
        return obj.Prop1 + obj.Prop2;
    }
}
```

Case 2:

```
[Route ( "api/[controller]" )]
[ApiController]
public class FirstController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string SomePost( [FromBody][FromForm] TestClass obj )
    {
        return obj.Prop1 + obj.Prop2;
    }
}
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50453578/asp-net-core-fromform-and-frombody-same-action

Comment: But there's an answer here that contradicts that, using Consumes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51735331/243245

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://massivescale.com/web-api-routing-by-content-type/

Comment: @Igor i saw it. I don't need to use only one action. I can make another method or contoller

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just manually read out the values?

e.g.

```
[HttpPost]
public string SomePost()
{
    // Check if it's a Form value
    if(Request.Form != null) { // do something }
    else if(Request.Body != null) { // do something }
}
```

Note: the code above might not compile, I just quickly wrote it in here.

Comment: I don't want to create a bike if there is another build in way.

Comment: Because then you'll have to do parsing and content negotiation youself.

Comment: It was an alternative suggestion @CodeCaster